# Header Title breaking in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, nowrap

I am working on this site: http://sbw.aaugirlsbasketball.org/

The client says that he is using IE 11 on a Windows 10 machine that that the title "AAU Girls Basketball" is breaking into 2 lines at specific resolutions. The are approximate screen widths found when using Inspect Element in IE on the `<header id="skin_header">` tag:

1. 1320px wide: OK
2. 1300px wide: breaks to two lines
3. 1140px wide: OK
4. 1065px wide: breaks to two lines
5. 984px wide: gets smaller but still broken, from here the text size changes but continues broken until 760px when it is good again.

Here is a screenshot:[image]

As you can see in the CSS below we tried to add `span.head1 { white-space: nowrap; }` to the but I guess it did not work. I can't get my IE to replicate the problem and neither can my developer.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="headertitle">
    <div class="titlehead">
       <span class="head1">AAU GIRLS BASKETBALL</span>
       <br>
       <span class="head2">THE OFFICAL HOME OF THE AMATER ATHLETIC UNION GIRLS BASKETBALL</span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.headertitle {
  background-image: url("../images/title_bg.png");
  background-position: 88% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 98px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -40px;
  width: 82%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.titlehead {
  margin-left: 49px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
 }
span.head1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
  font-size: 49px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow: 3px 5px 7px #070707;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
span.head2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Can anyone get this problem to replicate and offer a solution so my clients headertitle will not break into two lines as the screen gets smaller?

Comment: I tested in Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 10, and was unable to reproduce the problem. I suspect your change resolved the issue, but perhaps you ran into cached results leading you to conclude otherwise. Have your client press Ctrl+F5 to perform a hard-reload of the page.

Comment: I have tried this and used IE 11 on windows 10 but can't see it either. I will double check that it isn't a cache problem but it has been happening to him all week. Any other ideas on what could cause this?

Comment: Has anyone else been able to reproduce this breaking effect on another machine?

Comment: Does your customer still report the issue, even after doing a hard-refresh with ctrl+f5?